# Redirect Match 301 .htaccess Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Ok, so we are using vBulletin..ya I know.  Which is within our Kohana based system.  The breakdown is as follows.

This is how vBulletin marks its member URL's
http://server.com/forum/member.php?21148-username

I need to redirect them to this.
http://server.com/member_profile/view/vb/21148

In my .htaccess I have this rule

RedirectMatch 301 /forum/member.php(.*) /member_profile/view/vb/$1

End Result: http://server.com/member_profile/view/vb/?21148-username

It has a ? and i need to remove -username

I've tried several variations using $2 and so on, but it doesn't seem to work with RedirectMatch.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bit more in your .htaccess to accomplish this.  Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]+)\-.*$
RewriteRule ^forum/member.php$ /member_profile/view/vb/%1? [R=301,L]
```

That will take:
**http://server.com/forum/member.php?21148-username**

and return:
**http://server.com/member_profile/view/vb/21148**